# How we can get cookies of web App through inspect and import them to JMeter so we can pass some dynamic values to other APIs?

Tags: cookies, jmeter, session-cookies, web-inspector, cookie-session

I want to know how we can get Cookies of specific website home page from browser through inspect element, and then pass cookie data to other APIs as dynamic variable in jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

In your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) there should be some form of "Network" tab which allows you inspecting a lot of things including [Request Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

You need to take a look at [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

[image]

Once you get these "Cookies" in form of name-value pairs you can add them to [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) like this:

[image]

Once done JMeter will start adding the cookies to all [HTTP Requests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers in the HTTP Cookie Manager's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules):

[image]